# ANTLR - how to discard (free) tokens, to be able to parse large files

Tags: parsing, memory, token, antlr4

I'm trying to parse large files (200MB) with ANTLR and I'm having serios memory issues. Is it possible to free some of the tokens collected, to enable me to parse large files? I'm interested only in parsing (for syntax checker) and I do not really need the tokens, but I suspect that they are the memory consumer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Parser-method called setBuildParseTree which skips building the contexts etc.

```
Parser tp = new <ConcreteLanguageParser>(tokenstream);
tp.setBuildParseTree(false);
```

It will enabled lesser consumption.

Also, there's an antler fork that has lower memory usage:
https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/

Comment: That is already called, but the parser still accumulates too much memory. If setBuildParseTree(true) then the memory is even more.

Comment: @verbessern You could partition the input into chunks corresponding to a sub-rule in the grammar, then parse each chunk separately, throwing away all but what you need after each parse. There might be grammar optimizations you could do, but without seeing the grammar, it's hard to say. ANTLR maintains a copy of the text with the token structure. Consider defining a custom token stream that throws away the token's text since that is not what is used for the parse--only the token type is used. It's hard to say if that would save much memory without seeing the grammar and input.

Comment: You might also wanna look at TokenFactory and Lexer.setTokenFactory. It would allow emitting tokens without the actual text value, as @kaby76 suggested

Comment: @kaby76 I don't want very much to develop custom solutions, that have to be maintained for each future release of the tool. I hoped that there is out of the box solution/option. Even if I free the text in the tokens as you say (I have to try) that will still keep the tokens in the memory with all related pointers and the related memory fragmentation. Basically my memory will still be growing, even that I don't need the tokens at all.

Comment: @siggemannen Thank you for the pointer to the actual class name.

Comment: If anyone is interested, the solution likely involves all of the following: `UnbufferedCharStream`, `UnbufferedTokenStream`, a custom token and `TokenFactory`, and `BuildParseTree=false`. Antlr caches a lot internally (e.g., it reads the entire file into memory with AntlrFileStream, which was the first problem I noticed). This is as much as an "out of the box" solution one will find. And, it's possible that a custom token and factory is not required. But, I was able to parse a 2GB file with a regular expression grammar of "repeating a, b, c's", and the process memory maxed at 8MB (C#).